# Find the matrix relative to the standard bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:P_2 \to P_3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(p(x)) = xp(x).$

Find the matrix for $T$ relative to the standard bases

$B = \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$, $B' = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$.

$u_1 = 1, u_2 = x, u_3 = x^2$

$v_1 = 1, v_2 = x, v_3 = x^2, v_4 = x^3$

I'm a little unsure of what I am looking for here, I don't think it's the change of base/transition matrix?

Following the transformation definition I came up with the matrix $T$ for the standard bases:

$T(1,0,0) = T(1+0x + 0x^2) = x = (0,1,0,0)$

$T(0,1,0) = T(0+x+0x^2) = x^2 = (0,0,1,0)$

$T(0,0,1) = T(0+0x+x^2) = x^3 = (0,0,0,1)$

Giving the matrix

$$
        T =\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Agree, don't be afraid. It is correct.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Good job. You can think that since $T$ goes from $P_2$ (which has dimension $3$) to $P_3$ (which has dimension $4$), and you put things in columns, your matrix has to be $4 \times 3$. This is just a little sanity check, but it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are all correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$